What is the source of the following vedic verse?
Aham Aryah adadat bhumim..It was quoted by an Arya samaj Guru..where is it found probably in rigveda.?

This question is similar to: Where is the following vedic verse found? ("Aham aryah adadat bhumim"). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
